# How to generate gtag item list foreach product using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, each

Here is a short product list for the reference. I would like to have my gtag generated below the product list. How can I do this?

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="name">Audi</div>
    <div class="price">21.000</div>
</div>  
<div class="product">
    <div class="name">Opel</div>
    <div class="price">17.000</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <div class="name">Cadillac</div>
    <div class="price">33.500</div>
</div>
```

Here I need all the product values in the *items* parts.

```
<script>
gtag("event", "view_item_list", {
  item_list_id: "category_products",
  item_list_name: "Products from a category",
  items: [
    {
      item_name: "Audi",
      price: 21.000,
      index: 0
    },
    {
      item_name: "Opel",
      price: 17.000,
      index: 1
    },
    {
      item_name: "Cadillac",
      price: 33.500,
      index: 2
    }
  ]
});
</script>
```

**Updated code** using the method from the answer below. So now, if I pass the products variable, it throws a syntax error at the line **gtag("event", "view_item_list"**. The error by itself says **Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

```
<script>

var products = [];
    
$(".product").each(function(i) {
  products.push({
    "name": $(this).find(".name").text(),
    "price": $(this).find(".price").text(),
    "index": i
  })
});

gtag("event", "view_item_list" {
  item_list_id: "category_products",
  item_list_name: "Products from a category",
  items: products
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each` loop and inside that get the value of name & price using `.find()` and `.text()` method . Then , pass the generated array to your gtag items parts .

***Demo Code :***

```js
var items = [];

$(".product").each(function(i) {
  items.push({
    "name": $(this).find(".name").text(),
    "price": $(this).find(".price").text(),
    "index": i
  })
})

console.log(items)
//pass items in your gtag
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <div class="name">Audi</div>
  <div class="price">21.000</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="name">Opel</div>
  <div class="price">17.000</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="name">Cadillac</div>
  <div class="price">33.500</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost done! But for me there is one more question - how to pass the items to appear inside the gtag property. I'm not able to figure out even that one last step.

Comment: you can directly use `items: items` in your gtag.

Comment: I have tried to do so. Unfortunately, it shows items: items. It's not being replaced by the list. Maybe the variable is not global.

Comment: Console says that "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" at `gtag("event", "view_item_list", {` line. Maybe the list is in a bit different structure...

Comment: In your code you have `items
  items:` . why there are two items ? Also, can you update your js  code in question as well.

Comment: I have added the updated code at the end of my question. The syntax error still occurs. Maybe that's the reason the list of products is not being displayed in the gtag.

Comment: Hi, saw your js code and you are missing `,` here `"view_item_list" {` it should be `"view_item_list" , {`

Comment: Yes, that solved the syntax error. But the interesting thing is that it still shows `items: products`. It's not being replaced by the list. I guess this function prevents from passing any variables in this way. Maybe I will keep looking on how I can push products to that gtag function.